# Pie chart for pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pie-chart, pyspark-pandas

How do generate the same pie chart for `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame`?

 I'm not able to get the legend right.

```py
piefreq=final_psdf['Target'].value_counts()
piefreq.plot.pie()
```

For `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, I managed to produce my desired pie chart using the following code:

```py
piefreq=final_df['Target'].value_counts()

fig=go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['Yes (n=' + str(piefreq[1]) +')','No (n=' + str(piefreq[0]) +')'],values=final_df['Target'].value_counts())])
fig.update_layout(title={'text': "<b>Pie chart by target</b>",
                         'y':0.9,
                         'x':0.45,
                         'xanchor': 'center',
                         'yanchor': 'top'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded after transforming `pyspark.pandas.series.Series` object into `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` object using `piefreq.reset_index()`, as `plot` can be created both on Series and on DataFrame.

```py
piefreq = final_psdf['Target'].value_counts()
psdf_piefreq = piefreq.reset_index()
fig = psdf_piefreq.plot.pie(
    y="Target",
    names=['Yes (n=' + str(psdf_piefreq['Target'][0]) +')', 'No (n=' + str(psdf_piefreq['Target'][1]) +')']
)
fig.update_layout(
    title_text='<b>Pie chart by target</b>',
    title_font=dict(size=16),
    title_x=0.45,
)
```